# Tweet feature 'created_at' 10 digit number meaning

Tags: python, json, twitter, text-mining, tweets

I have tweet data file. Each has feature as 'created_at' in the following format:

```
u'created_at': 1369859382
```

What does this 10 digit number correspond to?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That could be a UNIX timestamp ...http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

The example you suggested is equivalent to `Wed, 29 May 2013 20:29:42 GMT`

Here is a useful resource for mystery date/times formats ... http://www.fmdiff.com/fm/timestamp.html?session=vc8uqio2fsg9op81ohnhbthclmsb21j3

Answer (score 2):

It is the time in seconds since January 1, 1970. The number in your example is May 29, 2013, 1:29:42 PM (in the PDT time zone, anyway, seven hours behind UTC).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1369859382)
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 29, 13, 29, 42)
```

Comment: maybe worth mentioning `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1369859382)`

Comment: Note that's a local time, which is why you have a different answer from the pi guy's answer. `utcfromtimestamp` will get you a UTC time, which is the timezone consistently used in the `created_at` strings returned from the Twitter API itself.

Comment: Good points, thanks. (And my time to edit them into the answer is improving... 2 seconds for Joran's, -83 seconds for Steve's.)

Comment: That's not pi ... it's just a coincidence. It's actually the amount of times I've unsuccessfully counted to 4.